# Adding a new per-user font directory

Tags: fontconfig

I would like to add a new directory to my user's font directories. To achieve that, I've added the following file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/dropbox-fonts.conf 
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <dir>~/Dropbox/fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

The reason for using a separate file is that it's easier for me to define it with Puppet.

However, the fonts are not picked up. As soon as I create a symlink from `~/Dropbox/fonts` to `~/.fonts/fonts` they are picked up.

How can I define an additional font directory in a separate file?

Comment: Could you run `FC_DEBUG=1024 fc-cache`, to check that your new config file is being loaded without errors?

Comment: @JigglyNaga - that was useful, thanks! The problem was that the config file did not have a numerical prefix, e.g. 10-blabla.conf . It works now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration file was not being picked up since it is apparently necessary to have a numerical prefix for the files placed in `conf.d` directories, e.g.
 `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-dropbox-fonts.conf` works, while `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/dropbox-fonts.conf` does not.

The leading `10-` in the file name makes the difference.